# Half opened eyes when exposed to sunlight

Tags: vocabulary

How to describe a scene where someone is not able to open his eyes while waking up in the morning due to bright sunshine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Squinting**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/squinting).

From American Heritage:

> 1. To look with the eyes partly closed, as in bright sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

dazzle

> to lose clear vision especially from looking at bright light

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dazzle

Answer (score 1):

One could **grimace** because of the bright light, but that's a whole facial movement, not just eyes.